# How to correct the mispelt words in R with a user defined words datarame

Tags: r, replace, tidyverse, text-mining, stringr

I fond that similar question was asked in previous posts but I feel my requirement is peculiar.
I have a dataframe which consists of one where there are reported misspell terms by reps.

Reported terms.

```
abdmen pain
abdomane pain
```

I have another data frame where I have corrected manually .

```
Wrong spell Correct spell
abdmen      abdomen
abdomane    abdomen
abdome      abdomen
abdumen     abdomen
abodmen     abdomen
adnomen     abdomen
aabdominal  abdominal
abdominal   abdominal
```

Now I need to correct the spellings in the reported terms as follows:

```
Reported terms
abdomen pain
abdomen pain
```

Could you please someone let me know what is the best approach way to do this task.
Thanks in advance for feedback

Answer (score 0):

Text correction is very hard even if you compare every word to a comprehensive dict, you never know whether words not contained are misspelled, names, etc.

That said how could you solve your issue?

1. You have to compile a dictionary of allowed/corrected words!
2. You have to compare each word in your uncleaned data frame to the dictionary using word-distance. You can use existing libraries [like this one](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vwr/versions/0.3.0/topics/levenshtein.distance) or code your own as the formula is not that difficult.
3. Replace each word in your comparison with matches from the dictionary that are above some theoretical threshold of normalized distance (lv-distance/length of source words).

Answer (score 0):

This might be the way to go...

**input**

```
#your current list of entries
incorrect = list("abdmen pain" , "abdomane pain")

# [[1]]
# [1] "abdmen pain"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "abdomane pain"
```

**code**

```
library(magrittr) #for pipe operator
library(stringdist)

#list of all possible correct entries
correct = list("abdomen pain", "abdominal pain")

#calculate stringdistance between incorrect and correct, 
# take the solution with the smallest stringdistance as answer
lapply(incorrect, function(x) {
  lapply(correct, function(y) {
    stringdist(x,y)
  }) %>% unlist() %>% which.min() %>% correct[[.]]
})
```

**output**

```
# [[1]]
# [1] "abdomen pain"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "abdomen pain"
```

Comment: I want  match the word which was there in the "Reported terms" to the wrong spell words and then updated the correct spell word which is against to the wrong spell words. I have written code accordingly to satisfy my requirement but its not working as per the expected output.     reportedterm_2 = list()

for (i in df1$reported_term){ 
  j <-   str_split(i," ")
  corrected_str <- i
  for(k in j){
    if(k%in%df2$wrong){
      corr = df2$correct[which(con_mis$old==tolower(k))]
      corrected_str <- gsub(k, corr, i)
    }
  }
  rbind(reportedterm_2,corrected_str)
}